# (Google Sheets) How to sync data validation for cells in two rows?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two drop down boxes, in B1 and B2. Both of these drop down boxes contain the same data, for example, {Yes, No, Maybe}. When I select a value from the drop down box in B1, I also want that value to be selected in B2, or vice versa.

For example, if I select "Yes" in B1, I want B2 to also select "Yes". Or, if I select "No" in B2, I want B1 to also select "No".

Is there a way to do this? Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will have to use scripts to achieve this and then use the onEdit trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Sinking Dropdowns

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 3 && e.range.rowStart < 11) {
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(e.value);
  }
}
```

[image]